# SSRS Report -> Filtering dataset with parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset which populates multi-choice dropdown. Lets call it "Company Chooser"

Since there are a lot of Companies I would like to add a parameter that would filter my Company Chooser.

I've added a parameter to report (with default value)
I've added Filter to my data set.
[image: Filter]

And I am getting an error
 [image: Error]

Is there something wrong with my approach or did I forget to add something that I should have ?

Second question would be - is there a way to set filter to something like "startswith"

Ps. Due to specification of project I can't filter thru query

Comment: What are the Available Values for CompanyFilterParameter? Are those coming from a query, or something else?

Comment: They are set to none - I would like to be able to just write in the parameter

Comment: Okay that rules out my thought then - I was thinking if you had the available values populated by the same dataset that you are then trying to filter with CompanyFilterParameter.